# return statement within handler sub

Tags: vb.net, function, events, handler

I have a form (CarForm) that is dynamically generated when a function is called (CarBenefitFrm) and it includes a checkbox which when clicked, will enable a textbox (HireBox). I've associated a handler with this textbox so that everytime the text changes, it should save the text in a variable (result) then return that result, this code is included in the Sub called HireInput. However, I can't put the function's return statement in the sub.

Below I've attached an image of the form

[image]

How can I return the variable "result" to the caller?

The only way I know how to associate code with a handler is to include it in a sub. I've read about delegates but don't know how I can apply it here.

I'll appreciate any help I can get, also a simple explanation on how delegates work.

```
Module CarBnft

Public Function CarBenefitFrm() As Decimal
    Dim result As Decimal

    Dim CarForm As New Form

    'CODE FOR GENERATING BUTTONS, CHECKBOXES, TEXTBOXES GOES HERE

    Dim HireInput = Sub()

                        If (IsNumeric(HireBox.Text) = False) And (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HireBox.Text) = False) Then

                            HireBox.Clear()
                            MsgBox("Please enter a number in this field", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")

                        ElseIf (IsNumeric(HireBox.Text) = True) And (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HireBox.Text) = False) Then

                            Decimal.Parse(HireBox.Text, Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint)
                            result = HireBox.Text
                            return result  'not working because return
                                           ' statement is within the 
                                           '  HireInput Sub                                          

                        End If

                    End Sub
    AddHandler HireBox.TextChanged, HireInput  'only know how to add code for a handler using a sub

End Function

End Module
```

Comment: Why does it need to be dynamically *generated*?  Looks like a garden variety dialog

Comment: ...and a `Sub` - including event handlers - do not return anything.  What would it be returning the value ***to***?  Windows invoked it, but it wont care about your result or know what to do with it.  If you are already capturing it to `result`, your work is done except to expose it as a Property or method

Comment: Instead of CarForm being a `Form`, create a new class for it. Define a Public property in the form class which can be accessed by the caller. Show the form with `CarForm.ShowDialog()` and read the property once it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for replying late. I finally managed to get the result I wanted. What I did is I made the form (Car Form) at design-time and then added a handler such that whenever I pushed the Accept button, the result would be save in a public variable that I created in a module so that it would be accessed in the form.

I then added another handler for the Accept button in the calling Form so that it would pick up the result now stored within the Public variable.

Thank you @djv for making me understand about using Property and also to @Plutonix for suggesting I design the form.